Problema con Twitter Cards en Wordpress
Hace un par de semanas estoy experimentando un problema con las Twitter Cards. OG funciona bien, en Facebook nunca hay problemas, pero las Twitter Cards funcionan ocasionalmente.
He revisado el código y las posibles fallas que podría hacer que no funcione, pero en ninguno de los casos hay algún error.
El sitio es www.emisorabullanguera.cl
Saludos

Hola Edison, bienvenido, los códigos y los mensajes de error, deben estar como texto, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y la adecues, así evitarás recibir votos negativos, y/o que sea cerrada.
